# Object of ‘NoneType’ has no len() - error

Tags: python, python-3.x, error-handling

```
z=[]
while len(z)<8: 
       z=z.append(1)
```

This programmes says error in the line where the while loop is. The error is mentioned in the title. What should I do ?

Comment: Just `z.append(1)` ; It does not return anything

Answer (score 0):

You should not use `z = z.append(1)` but `z.append(1)` as `z.append()` returns None.

After the first loop z will not be a list anymore, hence the error.